# V2DAP firmware working

Tags: ftdi

I want to know how V2DAP firmware works for 32 pin VNC2 devices. WRT V2DAP firmware is 32 pin VNC2 device compatible? Or should I go for 48 or 64 pin VNC2 devices !!

Please suggest me on the same.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your advantage of using the 32-pin package, apart from saving space? Or can you tell us why you want to go for the 32-pin package?

The application note AN_176 clearly points out that you shouldn't use the 32-pin-Version:

> VNC2 - V2DAP: Compatible with 48 and 64 pin VNC2 packages. Limited range of functions with 32-pin package.

Greetz